# Is there any login tokenizer machanism available in moqui

Tags: vuejs2, moqui

I am creating the vuejs app on node js and want to call moqui as rest API. So I just wanted to know is there any mechanism which can be call from vuejs and it will authenticate user credentials by returning a token, so for the next time it will authorize user by token only.

Answer (score 1):

Am I understanding you correctly in that you want a temporary api key to pass to other rest calls?

If so, have a look at the rest.xml screen in the runtime webroot folder. There are lots of examples there.